# ¿Por qué mis descargas desde mi programa en Windows Forms siempre pesan 1kb?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Los archivos los tengo alojados en un host FTP, cuando uso links de otras páginas los archivos pesan lo que deben pesar pero cuando lo hago desde mi página esto no es así, sin embargo, cuando descargo dichos archivos desde mi pc estos si se descargan con el peso correspondiente 
Este es mi código:

Aqui es de donde se va a descargar el archivo:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = "http://pie2.byethost32.com/uploads/Atom.lnk";



            Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri(url);
                string fileName = "atom.lnk";
                client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, Application.StartupPath + "/" + fileName);
                Console.Read();

            });
            thread.Start();

        }
```

Aquí es donde va a recibir los kb del archivo para el progreso del progress bar:

```
private void Client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
            {
                progressBar.Minimum = 0;
                decimal recibido = 0, total = 0, porcentage = 0 ;
                 recibido = decimal.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
                total = decimal.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
                porcentage = recibido / total * 100;
                lblStatus.Visible = true;
                   lblStatus.Text = $"Descargado {string.Format("{0:0.##}", porcentage)}%";
                    progressBar.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(porcentage).ToString());
                            }));

        }
```

Comment: Hola. Si estás intentando descargar un fichero .lnk, estos archivos son accesos directos y siempre pesan 1kb. Ten en cuenta que un archivo de acceso directo al abrirlo, abrirá el archivo al que apunta, pero al copiar, borrar, descargar, se realiza la acción sobre el acceso directo, no sobre el archivo destino. ¿Has probado intentando descargar otro fichero, por ejemplo un pdf a ver si te da un tamaño distinto?

Comment: Así es, incluso e intentado con un archivo .doc y el resultado es el mismo :/